# Are there any additional Umbraco admin URLs beyond mysite.com/umbraco/?

Tags: umbraco

I am not familiar with Umbraco and I am wondering if there are any additional admin related links beyond the /umbraco/ (for all versions of Umbraco)? Thanks in advance.

Identified /umbraco as the admin login, looking to see if there are any additional admin related links I should be aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, that one is all there is :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure additional if you like.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).